# Can I tell what property a generic getter/setter applies to in its body?

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

The context (`this`) is naturally the object that the property is being requested on, but there are no arguments passed to the getter function. I'd like to be able to get the name of the property being requested without using closures but it's looking like that's the only way to do it.

```
Object.defineProperty( someObj, "prop1", { get: genericGetter } );
Object.defineProperty( someObj, "prop2", { get: genericGetter } );

function genericGetter() {
    // i want to figure out whether this is called on prop1 or prop2
}
```

Comment: show some code on what youa re trying to accomplish

Comment: Can you provide some code explaining what you're trying to do? I'm not following you. Seems like you're hoping for a PHP-like __get magic method?

Comment: While I may indeed be hoping for that, this isn't quite the same. I just want to know the name of the property the getter is called on, from within the body of the getter function.

Comment: Pretty sure the getter is blissfully unaware of the property name that was requested.

Comment: Your getter function is a parameterless function like any other. Unless it's for debugging purposes and you're willing to do stuff [like this](http://eriwen.com/javascript/js-stack-trace/) to get the stack trace, the only way will be to use a closure of some sort.

Comment: So, wait, how are getters supposed to work if they don't know what they're supposed to be getting?  Well, without "hard-coding" the values (or keys).

Comment: Well the idea is you would have a different function for each property, or use closures.

Comment: @Rocket You bind getter functions to property names. In OP's example, reading the expressions `someObj.prop1` and `someObj.prop2` will trigger the `genericGetter` function.

Comment: @Rocket: they have access to the parent object instance (and all its members) through the `this` context, that's what should be enough for them to do some meaningful job.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: But how do you know if the `genericGetter` function was called on `prop1` or `prop2`?

Comment: @Rocket I don't think you can know. The spec states: ["*Return the result calling the `[[Call]]` internal method of getter providing O as the this value and providing no arguments.*"](http://es5.github.com/#x8.12.3). So, the getter receives a reference to the owner object (via `this`), but not the actual property name which was accessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I tell what property a generic getter/setter applies to in its
>   body?

That's not how getters work. A property of an object can either have a `value` or a `get` function. If the property has a `value`, then reading the property:

```
var x = obj.prop;
```

returns that `value`. However, if a property has a `get` function instead, then reading that property triggers that function. So, you use getters if the value of a certain property has to be computed dynamically, or if you want to perform certain operations whenever the property is read.

For instance, `.innerHTML` requires a getter, because its value is not stored statically, but computed on access:

```
var html = div.innerHTML;
```

Here, the browser has to serialize the DOM structure that is contained within the `div` element.

So, if you want a `.get()` function that retrieves various properties (Backbone.js has such a function), then you're not looking for getters.

The simplest implementation of what you want would be:

```
someObj.getProp = function ( name ) {
    // perform required tasks
    return this[ name ];
};
```

Comment: Still, there's no real reason why JavaScript could not (or should not) provide the property name to the getter in some fashion. Even better still would be a way to attach catch-all listeners on objects. I will be happy when that day comes.

Comment: @chaiguy Such a generic property access handler would be an interesting feature indeed.

Comment: @chaiguy Actually, now that I think about it, such functionality will ship with the next version of ECMAScript in the form of [proxies](http://code.google.com/p/es-lab/wiki/Talks)

Comment: Nice!! You just made my day, Šime. :)